# multiple variables stored in single node java linked list

Tags: java, variables, nodes, singly-linked-list, circular-list

I was curious as to learn how you would add multiple ints to a Node in a LinkedList in java (single circular). I had found a thread on SO and was reading on it but wasn't sure exactly how it worked. Thought I would revive the question to see if I can get an answer.

This is my Node class

```
public class LinkedList{
private class Node{
    private int pid;
    private int time;
    private Node next;

    public Node(int pid, int time){
        this.pid=pid;
        this.time=time;
    }
}
int size;
Node head;
```

This is my add which I'm just trying before I do any remove or anything like that.

```
public void add(int pid, int time) {
    Node curr=head;
    Node newNode=new Node(pid, time);
    if(head==null){
        head=newNode;
            newNode.next=head;
    }//end if
    else{
        while(curr.next!=head){
            curr = curr.next;
        }//end while
        curr.next=newNode;
            newNode.next=head;
    }//end else
    size++;
}//end add
}
```

This is what I have so far but when I try to input the two ints I get a null pointer exception at the `private int time` Am I doing something wrong? I'm reading in a file and then storing the two ints in a single node and then doing the same until the file is completely read through. I have the file reading in just fine and I have the two ints stored as ints from the file but I can't seem to get it to store the ints in the Node quite yet

Comment: You don't have problem in the presented code. Just make `Node` class `static`. Or you need to reference `LinkedList` from `Node`? Add the code how you populate your list object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How have you initialized `head`? Did you do `Node head = new Node()`?

If you make a custom constructor, Java does not add the default constructor anymore. You have to define that again.

You can instead do `Node head = null;`

Comment: @kevorski this can't be true :) uninitialized references are `null`s

Comment: @ValeriAtamaniouk for whatever reason it is now taking all the inputs and storing them into the LL

Comment: @ValeriAtamaniouk i'm not sure if there is something wrong but in jgrasp debug it looks like a second LL is created within the LL all with the same values

Comment: its a circular linked list. maybe thats why its not displaying correctly. your add function seems to be correct.

Comment: write your own display function code to check whether it is getting stored correctly

Comment: @kevorski you can close the question by accepting an answer if your doubt has been solved :)